# How is batch generator used to generate noisy data for a audio signal in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, signal-processing

```
#data generation 512 size 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def gen_signal_valid():
    signal=np.zeros((280000,512))
    it=0
    while(it<280000):
        sig_inf=gen_inf()
        Codes[it,:] = sig_inf
        sig = gen_code(sig_inf)
        signal[it,:] = sig
        it+=1
        if it%280000==1:
            print(it)
    return signal,Codes

def gen_x_valid(signal,Codes):
    x_train=np.zeros((280000,512))
    y_train=np.zeros((280000,512))
    for i in range(280000): 
      target_snr_db = np.random.randint(-5,20)          ####np.random.choice(test_list) .randint(-5,26) 
      target_snr = 10**(target_snr_db/10)
      sig_amp = np.sqrt(target_snr)
      noise_volts = np.random.normal(0, 1, 512)
      x_train[i,:] = signal[i,:]*sig_amp+ noise_volts
      x_train[i,:]/=np.max(x_train[i,:])
  #    y_train[:,:]=  Codes[:,:]
      y_train[i,:]=  signal[i,:]
    return x_train,y_train
```

Now I am generating signals using the above functions, as the input is large I m facing issue of slow training:

```
Codes= np.zeros((280000,15))
signal,Codes = gen_signal_valid()
x_valid,y_valid = gen_x_valid(signal,Codes)
```

can I generate signals and noise using a batch generator or store signals as a data frame and generate noise using a batch generator that improves training time??

Comment: These are the supporting functions:#data generation 512 size 
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def gen_inf():
    inf = np.zeros((15))
    inf[1:14] = (np.random.random(13)>0.5)*1
    inf[0]=1
    inf[14]=1
    inf[7] = 0
    return inf

Comment: Other functions:
def gen_code(inf):
    code = np.zeros((512))
    pos = 10+np.array(range(15))*29
    for i in range(pos.shape[0]):
        code[pos[i]:pos[i]+9]=(i==0) or(i==14) or inf[i]
    return code

def ident_code(code):
    pos = 10+np.array(range(15))*29
    inf = np.zeros((15))
    for i in range(pos.shape[0]):
        if np.sum(code[pos[i]-4:pos[i]+13])>=1:
            inf[i]=1
    return inf